# What i have to return after a DELETE?

Tags: rest, spring-data

I'm wondering what I have to return after that I call my REST API using the DELETE method. I wasn't able to find out any standard/best practice for this. At the moment my code base use 2 different approach, first of all return the deleted resource so into the Response Body I return just null. The second approach (which I don't really like) I instance a new Object and I return it. What you do think is the best way? If none of this two seems good to you, which one would be the best (practice) approach?

Here a sample of what I actually have: [code sample](https://gist.github.com/nerder/bce1cabce4a587b30f0b)

NB: Of course both of the described approach, are performed after the actual deleting on the DB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After successful deletion you should return empty body and `204 No Content` status code.

When returning `200 OK` with empty body some clients (e.g. EmberJS) fail because they expect some content to be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

I would return a `HTTP 204 OK` in order to signal that the request has succeeded.

If you need to return a response body, in case the deletion has triggered something, I would use a `HTTP 200 OK` with a body attached.

Comment: This is actually what i do, but do not answer my question, i'm asking what to put into the body of the response.

Comment: why do you need a body at all?

Answer (score 0):

what about Returning `void` wich means `HTTP 200 OK` in case of success

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void delete(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        service.delete(id);
    }
```

**EDIT** 
In the front Controller you can use something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public ModelAndView deleteMySlide(Model model,...){
    try {
        //invoke your webservice Here if success
        return  new ModelAndView("redirect:/anotherPage?success=true");

    } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
        //if failure
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/anotherPage?success=false");
    }

}
```

or :

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public String deleteMySlide(Model model,...){
    try {
        //invoke your webservice Here if success
         model.addAttribute("message","sample success");
        return "redirect:/successPage");;

    } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
        //if failure
        model.addAttribute("message","sample failure");
        return "redirect:/failurePage");
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually is exactly what the repository do. But if the delete(id) return void, what i have to put into my modelAndView?

Comment: you don't have to put anything, once you trigger the delete , the responce will be Ok if not an Exception will be thrown , you will have to intercept it and set a http status for it , in the front , you show a message if it delete is OK else error message.

Comment: @StefanoSaitta can you show us how do you trigger the delete on the front ?

Comment: I see what you are telling me, and i think this should be the best option. This is a short example of what i do at the moment, but i can actually declare the method as void without any worries about what return.
(Code)[https://gist.github.com/nerder/bce1cabce4a587b30f0b]